# My animation scroll is lagging, why

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to hide the menu when the scroll reach 150px

HTML:

```
<html>
<body style="height:2000px">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header{height:200px; background:#000; position:fixed; top:0; width:100%;}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {
            $('#header').attr('data-open','open');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 150 && $('#header').attr('data-open') == 'open'){
            $("#header").animate({top:'-180px'},500, 'linear').attr('data-open','open');
        }else{
            $("#header").animate({top:'0'},500, 'linear').removeAttr('data-open');
        }
    });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/egZ6H/1/

It seem working but when I go back on top, sometimes the animation to show the menu start a little too late and vice versa.

What causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `.stop()` before each animation call to ensure it doesn't wait to finish the last animation before starting this one.

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uqzp5/).

Code is:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 150) {
            $('#header').data('open','open');
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 150 && $('#header').data('open') == 'open'){
            $("#header").stop().animate({top:'-180px'},500, 'linear').data('open','open');
        }else{
            $("#header").stop().animate({top:'0'},500, 'linear').data('open', null);
        }
    });
});​
```